# error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'div_t' to 'double'

Tags: c++

i'm a beginner and my english is not so well so sorry first.
1. im trying to compile this code and i dont understand the problem- function div returns 'double', so why can't i write this line: "sum= div(x, y);" ? i tried to find the answer here and google it but it doesnt work.
2. beyond that, someone knows what is the solution to this problem- 1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED. ?
thank you for your answers!

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
class DivisionByZero
{
private:
    const char* zero_description = "error: division by zero";
public:
    const char* getZero() {return zero_description;}
    void printZero() { cout << getZero() << endl; }
};

double div(double x, double y) throw(int, DivisionByZero) {
    if (x < y)
        throw - 1;
    if (y == 0)
        throw DivisionByZero();
    cout << x / y << endl;
    return x / y;
}


#include "DivisionByZero.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try {
        int x, y;
        double sum;
        cout << "insert x and  y values" << endl;
        cin >> x >> y;
        sum= div(x, y);
    }
    catch (int a) {
        if (a == -1)
            cout << "x is smaller than y" << endl;
    }
    catch (DivisionByZero& c) {
        c.printZero();
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "unknown error" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: div_t is a structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the standard library also contains [a `div` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div), which takes two `ints` and returns a `div_t` structure. Because you're passing two `int`s in the `div(x, y)` function call, overload resolution picks `std::div` over your own `div` function. So you end up trying to assign a `div_t` structure to a `double` variable, which results in the error message you're seeing.

Some compilers also bring `div` into the top-level namespace (I'm not sure if this is defined by the standard), so even without `using namespace std;` this might not always work.

**The easiest fix (and least confusing for other humans reading your code) is just to rename your own `div` function to something else.**

This is one of the reasons that `using namespace std;` is frowned upon by some. It's especially bad practice to put `using namespace` directives in a header file, because they pollute the scope of any source file including that header. (I'm assuming that the first part of your code snippet is actually the contents of `DivisionByZero.h`.)